# Remaining used only before a noun

Tags: nouns

According to the OALD **remaining** is used only before a noun. But in the following sentence

[One option to see through their project of a life-time is to elect Mr. Hunt, a one-time advocate of **remaining** in the European Union (like Ms. May), and risk not realising the end goal.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/down-to-two/article28128685.ece)

Noun does not follow the word **remaining**.

Meaning of [*of a life time*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-a-lifetime)

So it should be used as

> One option of a life time to see through.........

Comment: The European Union is a noun. I believe it's always ok to add a proposition in front. There are two definitions of remaining: still existing, present, or in use; surviving.
2.
not yet used, dealt with, or resolved; outstanding. The above is an example of the first.

Comment: You're thinking of the verb phrase "remaining" that can modify nouns, as in "any remaining food will be donated to charity". In your example, "remaining" is also a verb, but it's not modifying a noun. Instead it's head of the non-finite clause "remaining in the European Union ...", functioning as complement of the preposition "of".

Comment: It is "One option to see through their project is to elect ...", and it is emphasising that the project is considered a lifetime's work, hence the noun is "project of a life-time", hence "Option to see through their project of a lifetime is to elect Mr Hunt and risk not realising the end goal".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sentence *I am remaining* ***to run***, and that's a verb. Or *I will remain and* ***eat***. Or even *I will remain* ***behind***. None of those involve a noun at any point after the word *remaining*. The rule that you're citing is either vague or wrong.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/remaining